# Difference in meaning: "He looked back at her." and "He looked back out at her."

Tags: difference

I haven't understand, what difference in meaning:

> "He looked **back at** her."

and

> "He looked **back out at** her."

Thank for your meaning!

This phrase from the book (no ads!), some wider context:

> Mickey carried the gems to the small bathroom and flicked the switch. “I’ll be damned.” He looked back out at her. “This isn’t natural?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"back" and "out" aren't really connected (e.g. it's not some kind of expression)... It means he looked back at her, and he looked out at her, simultaneously...